# Singleton class not update class member variable

Tags: python, singleton

I am new to Python and was trying to use an implementation provided on SO for singleton in Python. Below is the code

```
#################
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
#################
BNF_TICKER=260105
class MetaData(metaclass=Singleton):

    i=0
    token_price_ltp = {}

    def __init__(self):
        print("Meta Initialized")
        self.token_price_ltp[BNF_TICKER] = 99
    def setLtp(self,token,price):
        self.token_price_ltp[token] = price
    def getLtp(self,token):
        return self.token_price_ltp[token]


class A():
    obj : MetaData = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = MetaData()
        threadId = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run,)
        threadId.start()
    def run(self):
        i=0
        while True:
            self.obj.setLtp(BNF_TICKER,i)
            print("A:"+str(self.obj.getLtp(BNF_TICKER)))
            time.sleep(1)
            i+=1

class B():
    def run(self):
        obj = MetaData()
        while True:
            print("B:"+str(obj.getLtp(BNF_TICKER)))
            time.sleep(2)

a=A();
b=B();
b.run()
```

If we run this, we can see that class B is unable to get the value updated by class A. Can somebody help me to understand the reason and possible solutions.

Comment: ah, I think it is because the new process forked is unable to access the same copy of that object. So any solution other than IPC to handle this ? Else I will need to store the dict locally.

Comment: Yes, it is because you are using a subprocess, some form of IPC is required. These are *independent processes*, not threads.

Comment: Yes, I realized it after posting the question. Will close the question as I was expecting something simpler but of course local storage or IPC are the only solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, All the options to close this question are irrelevant in this case, hence I will need to answer and accept it.

To all those who are new to Python, whats happening here is

> multiprocessing.Process

basically forks a new process which has its on memory space, hence after the process is forked anything that is updated in the original instances and not available to this process and vice-versa, anything that this process updates will be updated in the copy of its own memory space.

If we replace that part with a

> threading.Thread

, when we can see the expected behaviour.

Now the question would arise as why am I not using a Thread here is that solves the problem.
It is because what I have read is Python has an GIL(Global locking mechanism), so multithreading is python may not help much in cpu incentive tasks (Non-cpu tasks like IO are ok to be multithreaded).
I have implemented multi-threading in some other part of my code but this particular could be cpu intensive hence I had the need to create a process.